# HTML - Adding labels to options in a combo box

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a combo box with labels on the left side and the option name on the right like this.
[image]
I made a `<span>` tag inside the `<option>` tag and in the css, I appointed `direction: rtl;` to the option tag and `direction: ltr;` to the span but it doesn't seem to work. How can I do this?

Comment: Why do you need to apply any direction?

Comment: The options are in arabic